# host local website on IIS 7.5 (Access Denied)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5

I've a simple asp website on my local machine which I'm trying to bring it up on local IIS (I'm using windows 7 professional), here's what I've done:

1. IIS => Add Web site...
2. Site Name => ticketing.com
3. Physical Path C:\Users\joshua\Desktop\ticketing
4. Connect as.. => Specific user => ASPNET + pwd (tested and was authorized)
5. type => http, IP Address: All Unassigned, Port: 80
6. Host name => ticketing.com
7. IIS => Application Pools => changed .Net Framework for ticketing.com to v4.0 Integrated
8. Changed the owner of the root folder and its all sub directories to ASPNET with full control
9. Enabled Anonymous Authentication and set it to "Application pool identity"
10. Modified hosts file and set my machine's ip to ticketing.com (192.168.1.55 ticketing.com)
11. Browsed to ticketing.com and my index.html page came up as it supposed to be (it's a empty html file with some random text in it just for testing if the website is accessible)

Now the problem is that in my root I have an login.aspx file but when I browse it I get the following error:

```
Access is denied.
Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists).
```

I've checked root folder properties -> security, the owner is ASPNET and it has full control over the files but still I couldn't manage to bring the login.aspx page up.

Any idea why is this happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have these lines in your web.config ? 

     <authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All" requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" path="/"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: Try to give permission to the folder where that login.aspx file exists....